# Is Character Stream capable to transfer binary files without corrupting them?

Tags: java

I was reading for a while about binary and Character Streams in JAVA, the Character Stream should not be capable to transfer binary files correctly, with other words, if we copy binary file to another one using Character Stream, the target file will be corrupted, but the result i get is not the same with what I was expecting,The files I'm trying to copy are images and videos.
here is the code I'm using.

```
public void charCopy() throws IOException {

    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(source);
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(target);
    int readChar;

    System.out.println("log : " + this.loggin() + ": copy successfully started !");
    while ((readChar = fileReader.read()) != -1) {

        fileWriter.write(readChar);
    }
    System.out.println("log : " + this.loggin() + ": copy successfully terminated !");
    fileReader.close();
    fileWriter.close();

    System.out.println("log : " + this.loggin() + ": streams successfully closed !");
    System.out.println("log : " + this.loggin() + ": target file ready !");

}
```

Comment: A character stream can only be *guaranteed* to carry binary data without corruption if the binary data is encoded to text. The most common encoding used for that is [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

Comment: Character streams, and `Reader`s and `Writer`s, are meant for *character* data - text data, XML, JSON, other formats that are fundamentally *text*. If you're dealing with binary files, you should be using `byte`s and `InputStream`s and `OutputStream`s.

Comment: Yes this is right, these objects are meant to be used with Character Streams and files that are encoded to text, but this code I'm using, I have copied with it a ".png" file without error and this should not work!

Comment: @no_pain_no_gain why do you say that?  It can work if you get lucky.  It doesn't _have_ to fail.

Comment: It all depends on the used charset (character encoding).

Comment: In particular `FileReader,FileWriter` use your JVM's _default_ character encoding. On Unix this depends on your locale, as determined by environment variables. On my (US) Windows it is always CP1252, which does reversibly preserve all bytes, but I haven't tried changing Windows region settings because it's much clunkier than an envvar.